# How to enable Developer Mode on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows

I know in Windows 10 Update and Security has the option to enable Developer Mode. The same setting is not shown in Windows 8. How to enable then?

Comment: I've never heard of Windows 8 having a developer mode, do you have a reference for that?

Comment: It was introduced at Win10.  Back then you had to get a temporary developer certificate to test WinRT apps, renewable once a month.  That was fairly annoying, DM was a nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Run this command in PowerShell:

```
Show-WindowsDeveloperLicenseRegistration
```

Then log in to your Microsoft account and accept your Developer license.
You will need to renew your licence every 6 months.